# What data structure to use for indexing data for partial %infix% searching?

Tags: java, data-structures, indexing

Imagine you have a huge cache of data that is to be searched through by 4 ways :

1. exact match
2. prefix%
3. %suffix
4. %infix%

I'm using [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) for the first 3 types of searching, but I can't figure out how to approach the fourth one other than sequential processing of huge array of elements.

Comment: Just a quick comment. For 1 & 2, you can use sargable inclusion conditions such as `=` and `LIKE '<literal>%'`. These typically allow the optimizer to use the index on the column.

Comment: How long can the `myQuestion` be ? More than 10 chars ?

Comment: @Sloin you mention in another comment that the average size for your collection is 5000 (not big). Why not iterating (for 100 000+ I would understand)?

Comment: Have you considered using full text indexing?  This is available in most databases.  Otherwise, store the data in a machine with enough RAM to put it all in memory, and you don't have to worry about scanning all of it.

Comment: @anymeric: it depends, small businesses would have 5000, but then we deploy that to big one and there would be 50 000

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? PostgreSQL can use a regular index for 3) and 4)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: SQL was mentioned just to point out what kind of partial matching wild card we talk about. It could be called partial infix matching.

Answer (score 1):

If your dataset is huge cosider using a search platform like [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) so that you dont end up in a performance mess.

Comment: We are talking about collections of strings with size avg. 5000. Lucene is overkill here

Comment: I would just need the algorithm and data structure lucene is using for what I need. Maybe I could take a look at it. The problem is that this kind of pattern searching doesn't really have a name...

Comment: I was reading through this [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search) on full text search.

Comment: If it is only around 5000 strings why not try matching using regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a navigable map or set (eg TreeMap or TreeSet) for the 2 (with keys in normal order) and 3 (keys in reverse)

For option 4 you can construct a collection with a key for every starting letter. You can simplify this depending on your requirement. This can lead to more space being used but get O(log n) lookup times.

Comment: Trying to undestand your recommendation for 4: If the existing string is "abcaae" would it match all of a, b, c and e?

Comment: For "abcaae" the set would look like { ae, aae, abcaae, bcaae, caae, e } You lookup with `floorKey(toFind).startsWith(toFind)`

Answer (score 0):

For #4 I am thinking if you pre-compute the number of occurances of each character then you can look up in that table for entires that have at least as many occurances of the characters in the search string.

How efficient this algorithm is will probably depend on the nature of the data and the search string. It might be useful to give some examples of both here to get better answers.